# How to create a serial task on the main thread?

Tags: swift

Since the main thread is inherently serial, is there a way to create a "task" on the main thread (in order to make a series of UI updates) that ensures no other UI update is interleaved with this task? For instance, suppose I want to make a few updates to the UI in an atomic fashion but there is an asynchronous download in the background that can hop on the main thread at any time and also update the UI. How can I ensure that the async UI update doesn't interleave with my other UI update?

Comment: You can't, not really, unless you're willing to write your the tasks to your own queue and have some other periodical task (in the main thread) pop of the next task and execute it ... as an idea straight of the top off my head

Comment: I’d suggest you describe what this “series of UI updates” consists of and what you want to do in your UI when the async download is done, and perhaps we can help you more. But the proposed implementation you are suggesting unfortunately isn’t the right approach. But it’s going to be hard for anyone to describe how to achieve what you want without a little more clarification.

Comment: But the one critical aspect of the main queue that you’re missing here is that it must never be blocked (because then UI updates can’t happen, you risk having the watchdog process detect that it’s blocked and summarily kill your app, etc.). You always must leave the main thread free. If you don’t want your post-download UI update to take place while your other UI updates/animations are in progress, then you’d have to have some state variable to keep track of where you are in this animation process which you post-download process can check and either update (or not update) the UI accordingly.

Comment: @Rob I understand what you're saying but the main queue is never technically blocked, it's still working, I'm just asking it to finish what it's working on before allowing other work in.

Comment: When you say “never technically blocked”, but that “it’s still working”, what precisely do you mean? Is it some `UIView`-based animation block? Or some CoreAnimation? If you have an animation block and then start another animation, the first animation block may not prevent the other one from interrupting it (though the particulars will vary based upon the type of animations and UI updates you’re talking about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to create a "task" on the main thread (in order to make a series of UI updates) that ensures no other UI update is interleaved with this task?

You’ve already done so. As long as your task on the main thread is running and doing its UI updates, it is absolutely impossible for any other code to be interleaved within it on the main thread. And since your asynchronous code will do its UI update on the main thread too, you are guaranteed that that will happen only after your task has finished.

Comment: Does that mean then that explicitly updating the UI in `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` ensures that closure as a task? And since the async update also must go in `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`, both tasks are guaranteed to run in serial? I know this is how it works in other queues, didn't know it carried over to the main.

Comment: Yes. It is a serial queue. However, it is silly to say `DispatchQueue.main.async` if you are already on the main queue. If you do, you risk another `DispatchQueue.main.async` getting in ahead of you. Just run your code on the main thread and don’t worry; it can’t be interrupted on the main thread.

Comment: For clarity, if I made a few updates to the UI within a tap gesture recognizer (not using `DispatchQueue.main.async`), that block of code must finish completely before another UI update can execute even if the async download returned in the middle of those updates?

Comment: Exactly so. Once you are on the main thread nothing else can happen on the main thread until you finish. The other update must wait.